# Sharepoint 2010 chart - Is there a limit as to how much can be seen?

Tags: chart-web-part

Sharepoint 2010 chart - Is there a limit as to how much can be seen?  I am trying to show (count) orders for a year by month.  It shows the first 6 months only and the 6 month is not the correct total.  Once it reaches 2000, it does not show any more.  For instance, if Jan - May adds up to 1990, then June will only show 10 orders.

Comment: What formula are you using?  Or are you getting your totals from within the SharePoint view?

Comment: I am using the count aggregate function on the field.